# RefineryCMS + TinyMCE + Integrate tinymce 3.5.6 with refinery 2.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, refinerycms

I am developing a CMS by modifing refinery, but instead of using the default editor I want to use TinyMCE editor but I am facing trouble integrating it with refinery. The editor tags does not appear on my text areas where I have specified the editor to be used.

Thanks in advance